# Find hash of apt-get package already installed

Tags: apt, hash

i have already install package using apt-get install. I want to know the hash MD5 so that i can make sure it is the same software exactly in other laptops i install. What command will show me the hash for this installed software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command called "md5sum" can be used to generate MD5 checksums for files as follows (Check "man md5sum" for more info):

```
md5sum [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

Regarding your question, if you want to verify before installation you can first download the .deb file using apt-get through the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --download-only <package>
```

Then check the checksum using md5sum of the deb and then install the deb using dpkg. Or if you have installed the package already then you can find the checksums in the directory `/var/lib/dpkg/info`

Comment: Where will --download-only download the package to?

Comment: What do you mean? The downloading directory of the deb? It just should be the current directory. If something is wrong you can also try sudo apt-get download <package>

Comment: yes this is what i ment, thank you! apt-get download without sudo worked for me and downloaded to current directory